# Identify empty area in a view

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-dialer

I'm extending the standard dialer apk in Android Marshmallow and I'm trying to remove the area marked by double sided red arrow in the picture below.
[image: Dialer]

I tried to do this by printing to log the margin and padding of some views in this fragment, but got no result (everything was zero). I also tried monitor.bat to see the tree of this screen but it also did not help.
Do you have any idea how to attach the 'Create new contact' to the number above it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I inserted the fragment SmartDialSearchFragment into my new fragment.
SmartDialSearchFragment derives from SearchFragment (Dialer's SearchFragment, not the support library one) and I made the method updatePosition() of SearchFragment empty (i.e., return immediately and commented all the code of updatePosition()).
This solved the problem (and hopefully with no damage).